# Cordova Windows Phone universal InAppBrowser within App possible?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-mobile

I'm using the InAppBrowser plugin for Cordova in Visual Studio 2015.  Is it possible to have this browser running within the app? Currently, my code launches the URL in the new instance of Edge:

I'm replacing the window.open with the following:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
};
```

I'm launching the URL with the following:

```
ref = window.open(
    url,
    '_system',
    'location=no,hidden=yes');
```

Having _system seems to cause the new instance of Edge to open.  If I use anything else (e.g _self, _blank) I get the following error:

```
The app can’t use script to load the (URL here) url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app
```

I'm hoping to have the browser run within the app to make the journey seamless.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

There's 3 points I've picked up:

1. jQuery mobile is required otherwise I get a blank screen
2. targeting _blank for binding the loadstop. Using _self broke loadstop event.
3. The following CSS class is needed to ensure that InAppBrowser doesn't have a massive border on windows devices

   ```
   .inAppBrowserWrap {
       border: 0 !important;
   }
   ```

I've truncated some of the code for clarity.

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>        
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>BlankCordovaApp1</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-mobile/scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-mobile/scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="MainContent">
            <label>Login here</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtUserName" />
            <input type="text" id="txtPassword" />
            <button type="button" id="btnLogin">Login</button>
            <div id="Message">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS

```
(function (){
   "use strict";

    var ref = null;
    var apiUrl = 'http://192.168.1.3:3000/Api/MobileLogin';

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;

        document.getElementById('btnLogin').addEventListener('click', login);
    };

    function login() {
        // disable login button
        var loginButton = this;
        loginButton.disabled = true;

        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: 'post',
            data: { Email: $('#txtUserName').val(), Password: $('#txtPassword').val() },
                success: function (url) {
                    LaunchBrowser(url);

                // re-enable the button
                loginButton.disabled = false;
            }
        });
    };

    function LaunchBrowser(url) {

       // _blank must be used in order for loadstop to trigger
        ref = window.open(
            url,
            '_blank',
            'location=no,hidden=no');

        ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (e) {
            if (e.url.match('MobileClose')) {
                ref.close();
            }
        });

    };

})();
```

The Web API returns a URL for the mobile to hit with a token (expires after 1 minute).  This logs the user in and sets a session variable "OnMobile".

When the user logs out via the web, the user is redirected to "MobileClose" because "OnMobile" is true. This tells the App to close the InAppBrowser.